# Get a partial string reading PORT via rs232

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this C# code for reading port via rs232

```
private void Recepcion(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
      Recibidos = "";
      Application.DoEvents();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(122);
      Recibidos += port.ReadExisting();
      this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Actualizar));
   }
catch { }
string text;
decimal dTEXT;
private void Actualizar(object s, EventArgs e)
{
     text = Recibidos.Trim();
     lblMSG.Text = text;
}
```

I have a weight attached to rs232 and i get Strange reading.

for example - if the weight show 14.23 Kg

i see:

```
14.23 Kg

0

14.

14.2

14.23

14.23 Kg
```

How to show the exact weight without breaking the string ?

Comment: That's entirely normal, when you call ReadExisting() then you just get the *existing* text.  Which is never much, modern computers are very fast and serial ports are slow.  Given the blank lines in the output, you'll be much ahead when you use ReadLine() instead.

Comment: thanks for the help, can i get sample where or how to use this ReadLine() in my code ? - I tried to replace  ReadExisting() in ReadLine() -But disappeared reading

Comment: You may need another value for the NewLine property, you'll have to read the manual.  If all else fails then you can set it to "Kg" :)